# nested div does not fill parent div with min-height 100%

Tags: html, css

1) I have a div.full with min-height: 100% (html, body is 100% height)

2) Nested inside i have a div.pattern with a fixed background pattern (an overlay)

3) and nested again some content.

I cannot seem to make the div.pattern fill the entire parent (if the content is small in height).
Preferreably I would like avoid js for fixing this.

i can't get jsfiddle working. will try psoting one later.

Comment: Does your background the size of the screen, or does it have repeat-x or repeat-x attributes?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: background is the size of the screen no-repeat (background-size: cover). @Scott I will post code later if needed. Right the issues seems to be found below.

Comment: @Scott jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAAsc/

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/ZAAsc/1/

I was missing a height on the pattern - but problem is still min-height / height not covering the whole content, if the content is larger than the space available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to use multiple backgrounds rather than the extra div overlay. I did it in the CSS2 pseudo elements fashion (::before with an background pattern) described here:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/

Answer (score 31):

An element can only get set to a height/width value in percent, when the height of the parent is also defined.
In your case, the parent has only a min-height, what is not an absolute height definition. You must set the height explicit to get a 100% height of your nested div.

Comment: but I have to figure out who to make the parent div larger if the content (now with height:100%) larger if the content takes more height than available in the browser.

Comment: @knalle Can you make a code example for that, to be sure we talk about the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Rather use `height: 100%` instead of `min-height` and specify this in both div.full and div.pattern

Comment: yeah that makes sense bot what if the content requires more height than the browsers height?